# Autowired fields required for constructor injection are null

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Required fields are not getting autowired in time when they are required for constructor injection.

I have a config class something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@Import({
        MigrationConfig.class,
        })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        MetricsProperties.class,
})
public class ServerConfig extends AbstractConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private MigrationConfig migrationConfig;

    @Autowired
    private MetricsProperties metricsProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ServerProperties serverProperties() {
        ServerProperties props = new ServerProperties(env, .., metricsProperties); //toString() method of this class fetches values from metricsProperties which is throwing NPE 
        return props;
    }
    ....
}
```

MigrationConfig.class

```
@Configuration
public class MigrationConfig {
   ...

    @Autowired
    private Repository repository; // in turn requires another bean & ultimately in chain requiring serverProperties()


....
}
```

MetricsProperties

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "csm.metrics")
public class MetricsProperties  {

....

}
```

So when starting application the thread reaches serverProperties() (as MigrationConfig requires it in its dependency chain) and at that point the autowired fields of ServerConfig (MetricsProperties) has not being initialised  resulting in serverProperties() throwing an NPE. (it prints some value it its toString() method)

If I comment out MigrationConfig, then while bringing up server it correctly injects the autowired values into serverProperties() i.e thread doesnt come through MigrationConfig

How can I resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Your configuration forms a cycle due to which some beans get eagerly initialized and only partially because not everything is available. Remove the cycle and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.springframework.core.annotation.Order

Comment: I tried using it but its not working. Wondering if it could be because Im Importing MigrationConfig. Even by giving it a low ranking, it is still getting initialised first 

also can the @Order annotation be used along with @Autowire?